# Live ISO not booting, unable to install on old notebook

Tags: boot, iso, acpi

Hey guys I am trying to install Ubuntu 20.04.1 on an old Compaq Presario C700.
The p/n on the back is FW081LA#ABM also C780LA appears there.
The cpu is an Intel Core 2 Duo T5550
Here is a foto of the bios screen
https://i.stack.imgur.com/62ic6.jpg

I am using the iso ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64 from official Ubuntu channels.
I am using Rufus to put that image on a bootable USB.
I have used this USB to install on different machines before, and it works fine.

I get this error
https://i.stack.imgur.com/EPJzO.jpg
It says ACPI BIOS Error (bug)
Excess arguments - ASL declared 5, ACPI requires 4

Any idea what causes this?

Comment: Without details it's hard to attempt to answer your question.  For example, how can we tell you whether or not you are using the correct version when you did not inform us exactly which version you are attempting to install? Where are you obtaining your installation media?  Are you sure that it's valid and has been created correctly?

Comment: For the sake of simplicity, let's narrow it down to ubuntu 20.04 i downloaded the ubuntu-20.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso from the official ubuntu website and used rufus to put the image on the usb drive. As mentioned, i have used the same drive before to install on different machines and worked fine.

Comment: Is your CPU 32-bit or 64-bit?  What is the exact CPU model number? There were a whole bunch of CPUs called Core 2 Duo

Comment: Does your machine meet the specs (minimum hardware requirements https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/SystemRequirements of Ubuntu Desktop)?   I'd use a *flavor*, and successfully test flavors on a c2d-t6570 (closest of my 11 c2d test devices), as I don't use Ubuntu Desktop (ie. GNOME) on that device.. it's not *fun*

Comment: May be a bit low on the processor (1.83GHz) but i did install 4GB DDR2 RAM so that should be alright. What flavour would you suggest?

Comment: The lightest *flavor* (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) is Lubuntu, but being Qt based (Qt5 *assuming 20.04.1*) the lightness may be lost if you prefer using GTK apps; so really only you can decide what's best for you (ie. your end-usage of the device, apps being used, plus of course your tastes/preferences). ; *yeah Lubuntu is best on my c2d-t6570*

Comment: Thank you all, I will try Lubunto!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Presario with the Intel core 2 duo may support 64 bits [see here](https://h30434.www3.hp.com/t5/Notebooks-Archive-Read-Only/can-my-presario-c700-quot-C762NR-quot-run-windows-7-64-bit-i/td-p/1131709) . But a recent Linux will probably not support your hardware anymore.

But: there are distributions out there, which will support that hardware. Try **MXLinux** in the 32 bit variant. I've done that with an old Thinkpad - works perfectly

Comment: Are you sure about that?  Most of the Core 2 Duos are 64-bit as I browse ark.intel.  I haven't found any 32-bit ones yet.

Comment: Yep you are right. 64 is supported by HP

Comment: 20.04 also has a very different message for that issue, ie. it'll report "**This kernel requires an x86-64 CPU, but only detected an i686 CPU.**" for 20.04.1 & prior media (alas the error won't dislpay on 20.10 and later; it's still there, but the boot process doesn't get that far)

Comment: yes, I've updated my answer accordingly. Thanks for your insight. I was too fast ;-)

Comment: So maybe i can try ubuntu 16.04 or would that still be too recent? What should i expect from MXLinux? Does it support libreoffice for example? Would be nice if my nephew could at least use this machine for his homework :)

Comment: I'd say that probably won't work, your device has been designed for Vista.. If my answer helped you, it would be nice if could accept it (there is a button below the lower triangle)

Comment: Ubuntu and most Linux support old hardware,  they are dropping support for 32bit.  Still running an old P4 on 18.04(last for 32bit).